# Jenkins AWS Codedeploy: deploy files larger than 5GB

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy build which is larger than 5GB and get the following error:

```
Zipping files into C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\#25-5190488528258686930.zip
Uploading zip to s3://***-***/#25-5190488528258686930.zip
Failed CodeDeploy post-build step; exception follows.
Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400;
```

Is there a way to solve or workaround this? (e.g using s3 multipart upload somehow)

Comment: How do you upload? AWS CLI should handle that for you out of the box.

Comment: I just use CodeDeploy plugin as a post-build action, specify "Application name" and other needed fields.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the CodeDeploy Plugin you mentioned above, but S3 has a 5GB per single PUT operation limit, which is probably what's causing the issue. Possible solutions for your problem include uploading the zip file using the AWS Pipeline plugin or aws-cli (as mentioned above by @Marcin).